# Noetherian local ring of dimension 2

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension 2. Assume that there exists an element $a \in A$ such that all the prime ideals associated to $A/(a)$ have height one. Show that for each nonzero element $b \in A$, all the prime ideal associated to $A/(b)$ have height one. Any hints or reference is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak m$ be the maximal ideal of $A$. Since $\operatorname{height}\mathfrak m=2$ we have $\mathfrak m\notin\operatorname{Ass}_A(A/(a))$, so $\mathfrak m$ contains a non-zero divisor on $A/(a)$, in other words, $\operatorname{grade}\mathfrak m\ge2$. (In particular, this shows that $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay.) Now let $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Ass}_A(A/(b))$. Since $0\ne b\in\mathfrak p$ we have $\operatorname{grade}\mathfrak p=1$. Then $\operatorname{height}\mathfrak p\ge1$ and if $\operatorname{height}\mathfrak p>1$ we have $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak m$, a contradiction. (Alternatively, since $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay from $\operatorname{grade}\mathfrak p=1$ we get $\operatorname{height}\mathfrak p=1$.)

Comment: I am sorry but why do we have grade(p) =1?

Comment: @random123 $b$ is a *maximal* $A$-sequence contained in $\mathfrak p$ since $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Ass}_A(A/(b))$.

Comment: I ws just wondering what if we begin with a different element in a sequence but that doesnot matter as the number of elements in a maximal sequence is independent of it and any sequence can be extended to a maximal one in particular the sequence starting with b. I hope i understood your point correctly.

Comment: This sounds right.